# Tensorflow variable reuse

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow

I've built my LSTM model. Ideally I want to use reuse the variables to define a test LSTM model later.

```
with tf.variable_scope('lstm_model') as scope:
    # Define LSTM Model
    lstm_model = LSTM_Model(rnn_size, batch_size, learning_rate,
                     training_seq_len, vocab_size)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    test_lstm_model = LSTM_Model(rnn_size, batch_size, learning_rate,
                     training_seq_len, vocab_size, infer=True)
```

The code above gives me an error

```
Variable lstm_model/lstm_vars/W already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?
```

If I set the reuse=True as shown in the below code block

```
with tf.variable_scope('lstm_model', reuse=True) as scope:
```

I get a different error

```
Variable lstm_model/lstm_model/lstm_vars/W/Adam/ does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

As a reference I've appended the relevant model code below. The corresponding section in the LSTM model where I have the weights

```
with tf.variable_scope('lstm_vars'):
    # Softmax Output Weights
    W = tf.get_variable('W', [self.rnn_size, self.vocab_size], tf.float32, tf.random_normal_initializer())
```

The corresponding section where I have my Adam optimizer:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
```

Comment: Did you initialize your variables?

Comment: Yes. I've got:
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)

Answer (score 10):

It seems like instead of:

```
with tf.variable_scope('lstm_model') as scope:
    # Define LSTM Model
    lstm_model = LSTM_Model(rnn_size, batch_size, learning_rate,
                     training_seq_len, vocab_size)
    scope.reuse_variables()    
    test_lstm_model = LSTM_Model(rnn_size, batch_size, learning_rate,
                     training_seq_len, vocab_size, infer_sample=True)
```

This fixes the issue

```
# Define LSTM Model
lstm_model = LSTM_Model(rnn_size, batch_size, learning_rate,
                        training_seq_len, vocab_size)

# Tell TensorFlow we are reusing the scope for the testing
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True):
    test_lstm_model = LSTM_Model(rnn_size, batch_size, learning_rate,
                                 training_seq_len, vocab_size, infer_sample=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use one variable twice (or more times), you should first time use `with tf.variable_scope('scope_name', reuse=False):` and next times `with tf.variable_scope('scope_name', reuse=True):`.

Or you can use method `tf.variable_scope.reuse_variables()`

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo") as scope:
    v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
    scope.reuse_variables()
    v1 = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
```

in code above `v` and `v1` are the same variable.

Comment: That's what I had originally. So I've commented out everything from scope.reuse_variables() and encountered the issue in the post as stated above. 

"with tf.variable_scope('lstm_model') as scope:
    # Define LSTM Model
    lstm_model = LSTM_Model(rnn_size, batch_size, learning_rate,
                     training_seq_len, vocab_size)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    test_lstm_model = LSTM_Model(rnn_size, batch_size, learning_rate,
                     training_seq_len, vocab_size, infer=True)"

Comment: What do you do before `with tf.variable_scope('lstm_model') as scope:`? It's look like you get variable `lstm_model/lstm_vars/W` in the code before this line.

Comment: Nothing. I think that might be why.